# Cannot run application installed using Setup Project in Visual Studio 17

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2017, setup-project

I have a Setup Project for my winforms application. After installing the application using the generated .msi i navigate to the installation folder and try to run the .exe file and nothing happens. I don't get an error or anything.

Steps i've tried to solve my problem.

- Making sure the target platform x86 matches in the main project, setup project and every other project in the solution that the application has a dependency on.
- In the setup project, made sure that i have a project output in the application folder that references the primary output from the main project. And that the dlls i use also are listed there.
- Ran the application as administrator.
- Activated Click Once security settings in the main project.
- Ran sfc /scannow without finding any issues.
- Restarted my computer.

When installing the program using the generated .msi on another computer i have the same issue.
When running the program from visual studion it works perfectly fine.

Comment: What kind of application is it? Console? Winforms? WPF? etc.

Comment: Have you tried adding some logging to your application so you can tell if an error is being thrown, etc.?

Comment: @itsme86 it's a winforms application

Comment: @BJMyers No but if an error is being thrown by the application a"Unhandled exception" dialog should be shown automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely that your application is crashing because of some missing dependency.

Possible reasons:

- A missing assembly (say, for eg, is all your third party dependencies present in the application folder after the installation ?)
- Difference between .Net framework versions between your machine and the installed machine (say, for eg. 4.7 vs 4.7.2)

One useful tool that has helped us in the past is to use the Windows Event Viewer. If the program is indeed crashing, it is likely to have details about the reason for crash.

You can then use it as a starting point for further investigation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i did not know about this. I am indeed getting two errors when looking in the event viewer. I will investigate further!